# syntax error: `newline or ;' unexpected

Tags: shell, unix

To simplify my problem, i am running manually the below cmds on 2 different unix box :

```
CURR_DIR=`pwd`

. ${CURR_DIR}/cfg_Contact_Archival.cfg
```

On 1 environment, this is getting executed without any error. But on the other environment I am getting the below error : 
syntax error: `newline or ;' unexpected

Could you please let me know what could be the reason for this discrepancy ?

Thanks

Comment: Are the two boxes both running the same shell? `echo $SHELL`

Comment: Yes Amadan, both running on same shell :echo $SHELL > /bin/sh

Comment: You can enable `set -x` or `set -v` to see where the error is being generated (enables echoing of executing lines).

Comment: @Amadan Got this with the above parameter : $ set -v
$ set -x
set -x
$ . ${CURR_DIR}/cfg_Contact_Archival.cfg
. ${CURR_DIR}/cfg_Contact_Archival.cfg
+ . /siebelfs/cfg_Contact_Archival.cfg
syntax error: `newline or ;' unexpected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities spring to mind immediately. The first is to check and see that your files do not have Windows-style CR/LF line endings.

The second is to examine the contents of `cfg_Contact_Archival.cfg` to ensure it's actually a valid `bash` file (since you're trying to source it with `.`).

With `bash` (and some other shells), you can convince it to give you each command line before executing it by placing `set -x` at the top of the file.

Comment: For the second possibility, i have compared the file(cfg) of 2 env. They are same. Please let me know how to check for option 1. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @paxdiablo I have just tried with running the cfg from the other environment and it worked fine. Will check the cfg file in my issued env.

Comment: OP is sourcing a file, so executing `set -x` right before doing that should be enough — no need to patch the file with a `set -x` on its top.